# iOS AsyncSocket in Views or Delegate

Tags: iphone, ios, asyncsocket

I got a connection if I use the AsyncSocket in the AppDelegate. Is it possible to define sockets in views? Because the method to call is named initWithDelegate. I only need the connection in some views. I also need this connection in a thread as aditional class. Can I pass the connection via Constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can. But you should probably add the socket as a property of a singleton class. That way, you would have access to from from wherever it is needed.

Comment: OK can I simply access the AppDelegate from a Controller? If yes how it works?

Answer (score 0):

Putting networking code in a view smells wrong to me.  Your views should handle display and user interaction, and should generally be agnostic as to where the data comes from or goes to.  That's the job of the controller layer.

I'm not saying that it's inconceivable that you might have networking code in a view (UIWebView comes to mind, but that is almost certainly implemented internally as a collection of classes, including controllers, and just presents itself as a UIView), but you should have a very good reason why that makes the most sense.

By using a controller you reduce the chance you will paint yourself into a corner down the road.